# Tile-based map solution supporting vector layers

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, gis, shapefile

I need to display a map of the US and, above that, a layer of states, another of counties and another of places ([as per defined by US Census](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/cob/cbf_place.html)). Also, depending on some criteria, I need to dynamically toggle one layer or another, and to colorize some parts of the layer (e.g. fill some counties in red, others in green, etc). The map itself can be plain simple, I don't need roads or anything that detailed.

My first attempt was done with d3 based on [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606), but I'd really like to switch to a tiling-based solution as it seems more responsive, lightweight, smoother and better supported for mobile devices.

I've been looking on the web for a solution (commercial and non-commercial, as a service or locally implementable) but I haven't found one to fulfill all my needs. For example, I've found [MapBox](http://mapbox.com) which even has a [very nice editor](http://mapbox.com/tilemill), but you can't fine-control the layers you define. I can hide/show a layer, but I can't colorize just a part of it. Google Maps was of course my first option but I didn't find a way to do as above.

Do you know if is there any solution out there that I could use?

Comment: Have you looked at [polymaps](http://polymaps.org) already?

Comment: Have you looked at OpenLayers? Fairly standard map solution for web.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look at the products supplied by boundless. They enable you to use a wide range of technologies and provide the final product in a number of ways. They use Geoserver as a tiling server into which you can output tiles or features depending on what your needs for that layer is.

You can connect to it using ESRI, Quantum GIS or use the included web based map. They are open source so there is a community version that can be used for free or a commercial version that is basically the same but comes with enterprise support.

You can find them [here](http://boundlessgeo.com/).